# How to echo out Magento meta tags in theme files

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a client that is requesting independent H1 tags which can be different to the auto generated page titles in Magento, i.e usually these would be category names, page titles, product titles etc.

As there is no field for this in Magento backend I thought the best way to overide would be if the user puts the custom H1 in the meta tags field and then I pull that data in the theme files if it exists or show standard title if not.

So for instance in:
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

We have:

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

My idea was to use the default meta keyword head tags and have something like this:

If this is not empty show it

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>
```

else show default title

```
<?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

Problem is the `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>` does not show anything when placed outside of its defult head.phtml template.

Anyone have any ideas how to get the meta keywords in any theme file in Magneto?

Magento ver. 1.4.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: That's because $this is most likely not within the scope you need it to be.  You'll be looking to do something along the lines of `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getKeywords` ...  Now there's a few variations, it could be a helper: `Mage::getHelper('core/resource')->getKeywords` and it could not be `core/resource` --  It could be `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getKeywords`  I haven't researched, but that should help get you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
$keyWords = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_keywords')
```

This will ensure that the keywords are loaded. If you review `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`, you'll find that the function `getKeywords()` renders the same result (be it with caching the keywords).